# Отправка команды enter в telnet через CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, telnet

Коллеги вопрос такой, пытаюсь понять каким образом выполнить несколько команд для конфигурирования удалённого модема через telnet в CMD. С запуском самого телнета проблем нет, (telnet 10.10.10.1), а вот дальше начинается проблема - для запуска оснастки модема необходимо отправить команду enter, подскажите как это можно сделать, и будут ли потом оснасткой восприниматься команды модема, такие как enable, conf t(интересно так же писать можно сокращённо или же полностью)?

Comment: "set crlf"?  или, как вариант, вставить из буфера ?

Comment: не сработало, можно подробнее как прописать команду?

Comment: Возможно, у вас команда "toggle crlf", это зависит от версии Windows. А из буфера вставить просто - мы когда-то (когда приходилось работать в терминале) делали так: открывали любой текстовый файл с более, чем одной строкой, в FARе, ставили курсор на конец 1й строки, копировали символ возврата каретки и затем вставляли в терминал.